# How do you call onNext from inside a nested Observable

Tags: typescript, angular, rxjs

I'm working in Angular2 with Typescript.

I created a function that creates and returns an Observable. Inside this Observable, another observable is subscribed and I want to call `onNext` when the inner observable receives an event. Here is the code

```
getImages(hashtag: string) {

    var imagesurl = this.flickrAPI.fetchImagesByTag + hashtag;
    return Observable.create((o) => {
        this.httpService.get(imagesurl)
        .map(res => {
            console.log("res");
            console.log(res.json());
            return res.json();
        })
        .map(res => res.photos.photo[0])
        .subscribe((result) => {
            console.log(result);
            console.log(this.generateImageUrl(result));
            o.next(this.generateImageUrl(result));
        });
    });
}
```

The problem is that I am getting an error that `o` is not recognized. Apparently from its position inside the `subscribe` callback, it has become detached from the parameter `o` that was passed in.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you post a syntactically-complete code snippet?

Comment: @RyanCavanaugh ok I just updated it to be the whole function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Rx.Observerable` has `next()` method not `onNext()`.

Comment: ... hmmm..not according to this video https://egghead.io/lessons/rxjs-creating-an-observable

Comment: why did you put -1 and change onNext to next in your example?

Comment: I was trying your suggestion... strangely it works now! So `egghead` is wrong I guess. I can't change my vote unless you edit your answer, can you please make small edit?